# clickable words within a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, click, jlabel, mouselistener

I want to have words inside a Jlabel text that are clickable, and I want to register a MouseListener for each word or getting the clicked word (otherwise). The image below demonstrate what I want. Is this possible ?!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can only make the whole JLabel clickable. But you can put several JLabels next to each other of course, making only a few clickable (and different in appearance).

You could also use HTML, e.g. in a `JEditorPane`, and make certain words clickable via HTML, if that suits your needs. I found something about that [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345547/GUI/java/Making-clickable-links-HTML-JLabel), and this is how it could look like for you:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", "Click <a href='pdf'>here</a> to display a PDF file. For more information click <a href='info'>here</a>.");
jep.setEditable(false);
jep.setOpaque(false);
jep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
  public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent hle) {
    if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED.equals(hle.getEventType())) {
      if (hle.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
        // display PDF
      } else if (hle.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase("info")) {
        // display information
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, but unfortunatly you code does not work for me and I don't know why (no error), and I have added system.out to print sth but nothing in the console when I click, also the text "here" is not as a link!?

Comment: I tested that code, it works perfectly for me. And 'here' is displayed as a link. Which JDK version are you using? Hard to tell what the issue could be: debug it, track it down. Of course, you have to add that pane to your JPanel or some other container.

Comment: I'm using jdk-1.6, and I have added the jep (JEditorPan) to my panel (I have mentioned that I can see the jep).

Comment: I'm using 1.6 as well. Like I said it's working for me, so the code is correct. Without an error it's hard to say what is wrong for you. Maybe try it in a stand-alone application, try to track it down.

Comment: just a mistyped word, Thanks all